# Rotate a vector to match another vector's direction

Tags: geometry-nodes

How to rotate a vector to match another vector's direction.

For example:
[image]

Comment: If you mean to keep one vector's length and an other's direction, then using normalize, length, and scale nodes will do.  If you're looking to calculate *how much* you need to rotate a vector to match an other one, this is much more involved and is naturally expressed with matrices, which nodes don't support

Comment: Thank you, for that case, I need the rotation.

Comment: Describe what you're trying to do because it's all very comfused, Take a look at the Align Euler to Vector node

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I figured out, any other better idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest solution is this one:

[image]

The node `Align Euler to Vector`, creates a rotation that aligns to a given vector depending on the chosen axis.